# How to write numpy arrays directly to s3 in a deep learning application backed by spark

Tags: numpy, amazon-s3, pyspark, deep-learning

We are generating ~10k numpy arrays using keras and then finally we have to save those arrays as .npy files to s3. But the problem is for saving to s3 inside the map function of spark we have to create intermediate file.What we want is instead of creating intermediate files directly stream them to s3. I used this "Cottoncandy" library but then its not working inside spark map function and throwing error as:-

```
pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle thread.lock objects
```

Is there any possible way/library available which we can use inside a deep learning application inside spark map function to directly stream the numpy arrays to s3 ?

I have my rdd of numpy array as:

```
features_rdd
```

options I tried:-

```
def writePartition(xs):
    cci = cc.get_interface('BUCKET_NAME', ACCESS_KEY=os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
                           SECRET_KEY=os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"), endpoint_url='https://s3.amazonaws.com')
    #output_path, format_name
    for k,v in xs:
        file_name_with_domain = get_file_with_parents(k, 1)
        file_name = ...
        file_name_without_ext = get_file_name_without_ext(file_name)
        bucket_name = OUTPUT.split('/', 1)[0]
        rest_of_path = OUTPUT.split('/', 1)[1]
        final_path = rest_of_path + '/' + file_name_without_ext + '.' + '.npy'

        LOGGER.info("Saving to S3....")
        response = cci.upload_npy_array(final_path, v)


features_rdd.foreachpartition(writePartition)
```

option 2:-

```
def writePartition1(xs):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3',region_name='us-east-1')
    for k,v in xs:
         ...
         ...
        np.save(local_dir_full_path, v)
        s3.upload_file(local_dir_full_path, 'BUCKET', s3_full_path)
        os.remove(local_dir_full_path)




features_rdd.foreachpartition(writePartition1)
```

Error:-

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 642, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1541683970451_0003/container_1541683970451_0003_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 600, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1541683970451_0003/container_1541683970451_0003_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 600, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
TypeError: can't pickle thread.lock objects
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "six_file_boto3_write1.py", line 248, in <module>
    run()
  File "six_file_boto3_write1.py", line 239, in run
    features_rdd.foreachPartition(writePartitionWithBoto)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1541683970451_0003/container_1541683970451_0003_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 799, in foreachPartition
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1541683970451_0003/container_1541683970451_0003_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1041, in count
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1541683970451_0003/container_1541683970451_0003_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1032, in sum
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1541683970451_0003/container_1541683970451_0003_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 906, in fold
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1541683970451_0003/container_1541683970451_0003_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 809, in collect
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1541683970451_0003/container_1541683970451_0003_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2455, in _jrdd
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1541683970451_0003/container_1541683970451_0003_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2388, in _wrap_function
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1541683970451_0003/container_1541683970451_0003_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2374, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1541683970451_0003/container_1541683970451_0003_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 464, in dumps
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1541683970451_0003/container_1541683970451_0003_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 704, in dumps
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1541683970451_0003/container_1541683970451_0003_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 162, in dump
pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle thread.lock objects
```

imports:-

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.models import Model
from io import BytesIO
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np
import logging
import os
import boto3
import cottoncandy as cc
```

So,basically the application works perfectly fine till features_rdd. Even I can verify the count. But when I am trying to save these features that part its not working. Added the imports above

updates:-

```
def extract_features(model,obj):
    try:
        print('executing vgg16 feature extractor...')
        img = image.load_img(BytesIO(obj), target_size=(224, 224,3))
        img_data = image.img_to_array(img)
        img_data = np.expand_dims(img_data, axis=0)
        img_data = preprocess_input(img_data)
        vgg16_feature = model.predict(img_data)[0]
        print('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++',vgg16_feature.shape)
        return vgg16_feature
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error......{}'.format(e.args))
        return []

def extract_features_(xs):
    model_data = initVGG16()
    for k, v in xs:
        yield k, extract_features(model_data, v)

spark = SparkSession \
                    .builder \
                    .appName('test-app') \
                    .getOrCreate()

    sc = spark.sparkContext
    s3_files_rdd = sc.binaryFiles(RESOLVED_IMAGE_PATH)
    s3_files_rdd.persist()

    features_rdd = s3_files_rdd.mapPartitions(extract_features_)
```

Comment: Can you show some spark code you have tried so far?

Comment: updated the post. option 1 with cottoncandy and option 2 with boto3

Comment: Is this the full stack trace? `pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle thread.lock objects`.

Comment: @karma4917 you can check the full stack trace. updated

Comment: Ah - I think I am getting close. What are your imports?

Comment: Added the imports above

Comment: Did you try using `mapPartitions`?  As in, `features_rdd.mapPartitions(writePartition)`

Comment: Yeah that also didn't work for me.

Comment: You are calling `features_rdd.mapPartitions(writePartition)` outside of `writePartition`. This is strange error.

Comment: yeah in the driver program, I am clueless now how to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you update the code on how `features_rdd` is defined?

Comment: Updated the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183316/discussion-between-karma4917-and-dks551).